# Why accessing values in dataframe and list are different?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a list a defined as: `a =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`;
then `a[0]` returns the first element in the list: `[1,2,3,4]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

`df` is represented as

```
0 | 1 2 3 4
1 | 5 6 7 8
```

If I use `df[0]` the following value is printed:

```
0 | 1
1 | 5
```

I would have expected the first row ie `0| 1 2 3 4` to be printed like in a list. Is it because dataframe is represented by `dataframe[cols][rows]` rather than `dataframe[rows][cols]`?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. in programming languages like C++ , and even list in python the syntax used is row, column but in dataframe it is column,row . My question is why it is accessed like that rather than row, column syntax. Any specific reason for that. Throwing documentation wont help.

Comment: @user9807101, If your question is "why?" I don't think you can find a single correct answer. I can think of a few reasons why it should be one way, or the other. All we can say is, "This is the way it is."

Comment: If someone downvoted, pls let them be specific why they are down voting it. my question is not about syntax. my question was about implementation since it defies common notation used in other languages and even lists in python.

Answer (score 3):

`df[x]` accesses column(s) named `x`.

`df.loc[y]` access row(s) with index `y`.

This is an issue with syntax, not how data is stored internally by `pandas`.

You should read [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to understand the various ways you can extract data from a `pd.DataFrame` object.